# returning array from function to main in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, return

what is the method to return an array to main?
I know the array is created but cant return it, so when I try to use it is says "incompatible types in assignment"?

```
int* get_array(){

      int i = 0, j;
      int *array = malloc(6);
      srand(time(NULL));

      while (i != 6) 
      {
            int random_number = ((rand() % 49) + 1);
            int ok = 1; 

            for (j = 0 ; ok && j != i ; j++)
            {
                ok &= (random_number != array[j]);
            }

            if (ok) 
            {
                array[i++] = random_number;
            }
      }
      return array;
}
```

then call it from the main:-

```
int main()
{

      int i;
      int* get_lotto_numbers();
      int numbers[6];

      numbers = get_lotto_numbers();

      for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
      {
               printf("%d ", numbers[i]);
      }
}
```

any comments will help thanks.

Comment: There is a mismatch between `get_array` and `get_lotto_numbers` - did you modify your example?

Comment: Also, you should probably `malloc(6 * sizeof(int))` rather than `malloc(6)`.  The latter will only allocate 6 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

Arrays in C are *non-modifiable lvalues*.  Change `int numbers[6]` in `main()` to `int *numbers` and you'll be fine.

Make sure to `free()` it!

Editorial note: It's a bit weird to have that declaration of `get_lotto_numbers` in your `main` function.

Comment: And it might be worth noting that in C `int *get_lotto_numbers();` is not a prototype and the function could be called with any argument list and the compiler would (probably) not complain.  It's also odd to define a function `get_array()` and call `get_lotto_numbers()`.

Answer (score 2):

pass in the array as an argument:

```
void get_array(int array[])
```

Don't return array, just return.  Then call it with :

```
get_array(numbers);
```

Comment: This is indeed a simpler way to go about the business when dynamic allocation isn't really needed -- and it isn't here; the array is a (small) fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

```
This should probably work for you.....

int* get_array(){

      int i = 0, j;
      int *array = malloc(6);

/*do your stuff here*/
        array[0]=71;
    array[1]=77;
        array[2]=72;
        array[3]=73;
        array[4]=74;
        array[5]=75;

      return array;
}

int main()
{

      int i;
      int *numbers;

      numbers = get_array();

      for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
      {
               printf("%d ", numbers[i]);
      }
}
```